# Where to put third party resources like Twitter Bootstrap or Jquery UI in Laravel folder?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am new in Laravel and I just want to ask simple question. I just want to know where should I put the third party folders like Twitter Bootstrap or Jquery UI inside Laravel folder? Should I place it inside the Laravel main folder? Like this:

```
mylaravel
 - app
 - bootstrap
 - public
 - vendor
 - third_party
   - bootstrap
   - jqueryui
```

Or can I place it everywhere as long it is accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put all 3rd party libraries into `vendor` directory. However if you have files that needs to be visible public you need to put them into `public` directory because they need to be accessed from the web.

As example I use Bootstrap with Sass. So I have it in my `vendor` folder, however some files from it (JavaScript, glyphs and basic styles I moved to `public/packages` folder.

So in your case if you have just JavaScript files or plain Bootstrap files (not Sass or Less), you could put them directly into `public` directory in my opinion.

Comment: Not assets but libraries or composer packages.

Answer (score 2):

Typically if you're not using a frontend framework or asset pipeline or installer, you could just place them in your `public/` directory.

It really is preference but that's the usual place where css, images, and js are put.